# Creating a custom android view within another custom android view

Tags: android, user-interface

So, I have the basic structure of creating a custom android view component locked down (i.e. create the view's layout xml, create a class for that view that references the layout xml, and then use the class name in an layout xml that uses the custom view) and that's all fine.

However, if I have a set of custom android UI components, can I combine them to create an even bigger custom android UI component? And if so, how would i reference the "inner" custom android UI components in the class that defines the "outer" android UI component?

The real issue here is that the [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html) Class used to extract values for a custom UI component has only methods for extracting individual attributes (e.g. there is a "getString()" but no "[] getString()" that would return an array of strings that would then be used to update a set of custom UI components at once).

Is it possible in android to create a composite custom android UI component made up of custom android UI components?

(updated: Here is a link. http://postimg.org/image/nbnfq4nlp/2916ab5b/. Here a set of one QRCode Image, time and location TextViews form one Custom View (QRCodeScanItemView) while a group of QRCodeScanItemViews and the prominent date form another View)

Comment: post links to pictures to show what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks @pskink. Just added a link to the image

Comment: so whats the problem with creating two custom views?

Comment: I can create the "inner" custom view (QRcode, TextView with Time scan was taken and TextView with location when scan was taken). But I need to group a set of these "inner" custom views and add a TextView with the date that all these views were taken into one custom view.

Comment: just use layout xml like this: <MyOuterView> <TextView/> <MyInnerView/> <MyInnerView/> <TextView/> <MyInnerView/> </MyOuterView>

Comment: Thanks @pskink. You mean something like this ` <prism.re.gan.prism.ui.scan.QRCodeItemScanGroup
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <prism.re.gan.prism.ui.scan.QRCodeItemScan                    
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </prism.re.gan.prism.ui.scan.QRCodeItemScan>
            </prism.re.gan.prism.ui.scan.QRCodeItemScanGroup>
`

Comment: yes, exactly, try that

Comment: @pskink Breaking down the problem, I created a custom UI component and then embedded a standard Android UI View `<prism.re.gan.prism.ui.scan.QRCodeItemScanGroup
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/scan_group_date"
                    android:text="text...."
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />` but only a blank custom view with no TextView is shown

Comment: Here's better formatted XML for the above http://paste.ofcode.org/RjxEV2f7MqXeJR7nRGWy6P

Comment: what class does QRCodeItemScanGroup extend? do you override onLayout/onMeasure?

Comment: I am extending onLayout() so that my QRCodeItemScanGroup  is now a custom ViewGroup. It now works when i embed the <TextView> in a <QRCodeItemScanGroup> in an xml layout. I am now figuring out how to reference the QRCodeItemScanGroup  (and its "inner" TextViews) in code so that I can dynamically create more QRCodeItemScanGroup (with different "inner" TextViews) and add them to a HorizontalScrollView.